# Highcharts : How to display the values of the last series only

Tags: charts, highcharts, jasper-reports, line

I'm asking for your help with a problem

I would like to display the values of the last series, to have better readability.

I have produced a graph (HTML5 Chart Line) on which the progress rate is represented per working day. As you can see, it quickly becomes unreadable.

My objective is to display the values of the last series. 
So here it is the series: 2019-June and in 1 week, it will be necessary to display the new series which will be: 2019-July. And so on and so forth.

Please find below my "fiddle", it is only a light example

[Link to my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lx1tmeqo/1/)

regards.

NB: I'm working with Jaspersoft® Studio Professional 7.2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can enable `dataLabels` for a single series:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    ...,

    series: [{
            name: '2018-Septembre',
            data: [...]
        },
        {
            name: '2019-Janvier',
            data: [...]
        },
        {
            name: '2019-mars',
            data: [...]
        },
        {
            name: '2019-Juin',
            data: [...],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }

    ]
});
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jva894ym/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels